# Чем отличается секция _stext от _text?

Tags: linux, c, unix, gcc, ld

Файл *System.map* . Там есть символы _text, _stext, _etext. Как я понял _stext это символ, адрес которого это начало секции кода,  а _etext адрес конца. Тогда чем отличается _text и _stext? Причём _stext идёт после _text в таблице символов.

```
    0000000001000000 A phys_startup_64
    ffffffff81000000 T _text
    ffffffff81000000 T startup_64
    ffffffff81000110 T secondary_startup_64
    ffffffff810001a9 t verify_cpu
    ffffffff810002a0 T start_cpu0
    ffffffff810002b5 t bad_address
    ffffffff810002b8 T _stext
    ffffffff81001000 T hypercall_page
    ...
    ffffffff81808730 T bad_from_user
    ffffffff81808736 t bad_to_user
    ffffffff81808e57 T _etext
```

Comment: Это зависит от того, как эти символы используются в скрипте линкера (*.ld). Выложите его сюда.

Comment: @maestro оказывается я видел это System.map. Не знаю как посмотреть скрипт ld.

Comment: Нет, это выходной файл линкера, который показывает, где фактически разместились переменные, функции, константы и другие символы. Нужен входной файл. Он должен лежать где-то в каталоге проекта. Внутри него должно быть что-то такое: `SECTION 
 { 
   ouptut; 
   {
   file1(.text) 
   . = . + 1000;
   file2(.text)
   . += 1000;
   file3(.text)
   } = 0x1234;
 }`

Comment: Ну или `system.map` тогда выложите. Можно какую-то информацию из него выдернуть.

Comment: @maestro изменил вопрос. А как узнать сборка была с каким-то *.ld или с default script?

Comment: Так вы сами собирали код? присутствует там Makefile? Там должно быть что-то вроде `$(ELF_IMAGE) : $(OBJS) $(LINKER_SCRIPT)`, где LINKER_SCRIPT - символ, которому где-то присвоен путь к ld-файлу. А по этому фрагменту map-файла мало что понятно.

Comment: @maestro это ядро Fedora. Я посмотрел на http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ Makefile- там нет подобного

Comment: @maestro наверно надо еще вычислить где были определены эти символы- в скрипте или ранее в исходном С коде

Answer (score 2):

Оказывается все эти символы определялись в скрипте линкера ld. [(kernel/vmlinux.lds.S)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S)

`_text` это адрес начала секции `.text`. `_stext` это адрес кода ядра (сразу после bootstrapping code).